# How to share a url in facebook which holds a session value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, session, c#-4.0

In my web application I have a certain url http://mywebsite.com/OnlineStore/Guess

which I'd let the users to share that particular url or link into facebook. On that url it

holds a session variable called **Session[ProductId]** which is used to query certain sets of

data in order to display them into the said url. So I guess my question is I want to know

exactly how to insert or pass that session value along with the url to be shared to

facebook. So far, I tried something like this :

```
 <a id="sharefblink" target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
u=@Request.Url.ToString()"></a>
```

and

```
<a id="sharefblink" target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
u=http://mywebsite.com/OnlineStore/Guess/?@Session[ProductId]"></a>
```

but it says on facebook page, **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
Which I understand that the session value was not passed. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that error message? As long as you put the parameter into the URL correctly, there should be no problem. You have to set the `og:url` meta tag to that same value though.

Comment: I know the error message because it shows on the FB share link page preview. But for url that doesn't holds any session value it works fine. What is og:url in the meta tag. I'm not understanding it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Comment: Ok so basically under the og:url facebook doesn't accept urls with session variables, it should be undecorated urls. I was thinking it was possible

Comment: That only means that you should not include session _ids_. You can of course include “normal” parameters, that make your server respond with a certain piece of content. If that parameter values _comes from_ your session, that is not an issue. You should just see to it that your server always responds with correct content for that parameter – even if the FB scraper requests the data from the URL in a week or a month from now (which they will do periodically, to update their cache), which is usually longer than a session “lives”.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. that is my my problem because I don't use other parameters to display content into my view beside session variable. It can be still shared to FB though but the appearance is displaying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Which I guess because of the session id.

Comment: That error message seems to come from your site. // You should create an URL that gets all the necessary data passed as GET parameters, and delivers the correct content based on that.

Comment: No, the site has no problem at all, what I'm saying is it can still be shared into facebook and still you can open the link or url content with the exact content but my concern is the appearance on facebook. It appears on facebook news feed or the user's timeline "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." instead of an image with description.

Comment: I see also other problem with using session when sharing them to any other social media sites is that url or the link will expire which I guess why FB doesn't  require session to use in the link

Comment: So in your opinion, what is the best parameters to use aside from session in order to pass the values necessary to the view for display?

Comment: URL/GET parameters. Facebook makes a GET request for your URL to read the meta data, so GET is the only way to pass information.

Comment: Ok sorry for the late reply again. I think this is the first time I have to use the GET parameters so I need more to understand how it works in asp.net mvc.Given this example as url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784791/how-to-share-a-url-in-facebook-which-holds-a-session-value?. I believe questions is the method so I'd like to know what is 34784791? and how-to-share-a-url-in-facebook-which-holds-a-session-value?. How they put them all together in one url?

Comment: _“so I'd like to know what is 34784791”_ – that’s the id of your question here, most likely a database record id – and that is used to look up the right content for this page. (And that value is the only one that matters, the rest of the URL is just “sugar” for the human eye – you could call `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784791` or even `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784791/I-completely-made-this-part-up` if you like, and would still end up on this page.)

Comment: Ok so how did they put in there? Can you give me an example using a method and controller to put that id in. Let's say I have controller = Home and method = Index.

Comment: That’s a bit too broad of a topic to discuss here in the scope of this question IMHO. There should be enough beginner’s tutorials out there for the system you are using.